# Delphi TGPImage как сделать изображение черно-белым

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, gdi+

Использую библиотеки для наложения текста на изображение Winapi.GDIPAPI, Winapi.GDIPOBJ, Winapi.GDIPUTIL. Открываю изображение, добавляю текст и сохраняю:

```
  imgGPI := TGPImage.Create(fileName);
  graphicsGDIPlus := TGPGraphics.Create(imgGPI);
  // как мне сделать черно-белым? 
  // делаю добавление текста  ....
  GetEncoderClsid('image/jpeg', encoderClsid);
  imgGPI.Save(FileNameResult, encoderClsid);
```

осталось понять как сделать черно белым

Comment: Работайте непосредственно с битмапом. Вам нужно ч/б или всё же в градациях серого?

Comment: grayscale подойдет. избавится от всех цветов RGB. Как это сделать можно?

Comment: Y := Round((0.299 * R) + (0.587 * G) + (0.114 * B)); Вроде бы так по стандарту. И я бы плясал не от TGPImage, а от его потомка - TGPBitmap.